# WSDL targetNamespace differ per environment

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, schema

I'm the client of a SOAP web service created by a 3rd party.

They defined different `targetNamespace`s for each environment (dev vs prod) , each corresponding to the URI where that WSDL is hosted.

Eg; dev/uat environment:

- URI: https://uat.company.com/WCFClient/Client.svc?singleWsdl
- WSDL contains `targetNamespace="https://uat.company.com/WCFClient"`

prod environment (www instead of uat):

- URI: https://www.company.com/WCFClient/Client.svc?singleWsdl
- WSDL contains `targetNamespace="https://www.company.com/WCFClient"`

[image]
* *the screenshot leaves out parts of the WSDL*

When generating code from these (XSD + wsdl2java) it generates different packages named after the targetNamespace.
My code then imports the specific package.

This means that when my code in develop is merged to master(prod) I'd have to switch to their `www` WSDL , generate again, and then adjust my imports to that.

I've never encountered this before and never had to think about this aspect in this way before.
AFAIK a provider would have a WSDL that is deployed to their DEV environment, with a fixed targetNamespace (despite the URI where it is hosted) and that same code is then later deployed to production, where the WSDL stays the same, despite being hosted at a different URI?

My knowledge is limited as to the finer details, am I missing something re WSDL spec? Or is it something in the process that we're doing wrong?

**Additional Concerns**
This means that on the service side, they had in dev a version of the WSDL/code/spec that was tested by them and their clients.

To go to production, values would be changed, which means the production version is not the tested version?

Comment: you can manually set package name for generated classes in wsdl2java

Answer (score 0):

If the **only** difference between the WSDL's is the `targetNamespace`, then you should be able to use the same JAXB generated artifacts for both Service's. The only generated class that is important is the SEI(Service Endpoint Interface). When creating a `Service`, you can pass both a WSDL and a Qualified Name. Also when creating a Port you can pass the SEI of your choice.

Example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        boolean isProd = Boolean.valueOf(args[0]);

        //Pick the WSDL to Point to
        URL wsdl = 
            new URL(
                (isProd) 
                ? "http://localhost:8080/prod?wsdl" 
                : "http://localhost:8888/uat?wsdl"
        );

        //Pick the NameSpace for the Service
        String targetNamespace = 
                (isProd)
                ? "com.calvinmmiller.prod"
                : "com.calvinmmiller.uat";


        //Create the Service with the WSDL and Service of your choice
        MyAgeService service = new MyAgeService(wsdl, new QName(targetNamespace, "MyAgeService"));

        //Use the service to get whichever Port that you need
        if(!isProd){
            MyAge port = service.getPort(MyAge.class);
            int age = port.getAge();
            System.out.println(age);
        } else {
            MyAgeProd port = service.getPort(MyAgeProd.class);
            int age = port.getAge();
            System.out.println(age);
        }

    }
}
```

As for whether or not they created 2 separate services for Production or Development, I doubt it. If they created the Service using JAX-WS, targetNamespace is just a String value that can be dynamic.

Hope this helps!